# ERROR 1200 : Pig script failed to parse

Tags: apache-pig

I am getting error on executing below:

```
data1 = load '/user/pig/join2_genchanA.txt' using PigStorage(',')as (showname:chararray, channelname:chararray); 

data2 = load '/user/pig/join2_gennumA.txt' using PigStorage(',')as (showname:chararray, showviewer:long); 

joindata = join data1 by showname, data2 by showname; 

bat = filter joindata by channelname=='BAT'; 

foreachviewer = FOREACH bat GENERATE channelname, showviewer; 

foreachgroupall = GROUP foreachviewer all; batsum = FOREACH foreachgroupall GENERATE SUM(bat.showviewers);
```

Now I am getting below error:

```
"2017-09-15 04:01:03,517 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: **Pig script failed to parse**:  <line 28, column 46> Invalid scalar projection: bat Details at logfile: /home/cloudera/pig_1504878875671.log"
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Error mentions line 28 Column 46. What line is 28 in your script? Script looks like lot smaller than what the error indicates.

Comment: Hi inquisitive_mind, this is the only code. The line value 28 means, there were 27 lines executed before the error line code.

Answer (score 0):

It's saying field bat is not available in alias foreachgroupall.

Do a DESCRIBE on foreachgroupall, it will show the field names.

Replace the last line in your code snippet with the below one -

```
batsum = FOREACH foreachgroupall GENERATE SUM(foreachviewer.data2::showviewer);
```

I would suggest you to filter earlier after reading the data sets rather than filtering for channel name BAT after the join. See code snippet below for details -

```
data1 = load '/user/pig/join2_genchanA.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (showname:chararray, channelname:chararray); 

data2 = load '/user/pig/join2_gennumA.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (showname:chararray, showviewer:long); 

bat = FILTER data1 BY channelname=='BAT'; 

joindata = join bat by showname, data2 by showname; 

foreachviewer = FOREACH joindata GENERATE bat::channelname AS channelname, data2::showviewer AS showviewer; 

req_stats = FOREACH(GROUP foreachviewer ALL) GENERATE SUM(foreachviewer.showviewer);

DUMP req_stats;
```